# Magento 2.1 WSDL list error

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm trying to get the WSDL services list on a local dev server, entering the url below in a browser as per the documentation at http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/soap/bk-soap.html

```
http://mu2.dev/soap/default?wsdl_list=1
```

I get the error response below. Does anyone know why? I've tried various permutations of the url with no luck.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:m="http%3A%2F%2Fmu2.dev%2Fsoap%2Fdefault%3Fwsdl%3D1">
     <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
           <env:Code>
              <env:Value>env:Receiver</env:Value>
           </env:Code>
           <env:Reason>
              <env:Text xml:lang="en">Class &quot;array&quot; does not exist. Please note that namespace must be specified.</env:Text>
           </env:Reason>
           <env:Detail><m:GenericFault><m:Trace>&lt;![CDATA[#0 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(229): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;register('array')
  #1 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(198): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;_processMethod(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection), 'CatalogDataCate...')
  #2 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(162): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;_processComplexType('\\Magento\\Catalo...')
  #3 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(229): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;register('\\Magento\\Catalo...')
  #4 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(198): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;_processMethod(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection), 'CatalogDataCate...')
  #5 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/TypeProcessor.php(162): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;_processComplexType('Magento\\Catalog...')
  #6 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(91): Magento\Framework\Reflection\TypeProcessor-&gt;register('Magento\\Catalog...')
  #7 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/Config/ClassReflector.php(72): Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector-&gt;extractMethodData(Object(Zend\Code\Reflection\MethodReflection))
  #8 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(119): Magento\Webapi\Model\Config\ClassReflector-&gt;reflectClassMethods('Magento\\Catalog...', Array)
  #9 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/ServiceMetadata.php(148): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata-&gt;initServicesMetadata()
  #10 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Model/AbstractSchemaGenerator.php(75): Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata-&gt;getServicesConfig()
  #11 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Soap.php(137): Magento\Webapi\Model\AbstractSchemaGenerator-&gt;getListOfServices()
  #12 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Soap/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
  #13 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap\Interceptor-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
  #14 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http-&gt;launch()
  #15 /Users/mstadler/src/mu2017/mu2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap-&gt;run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
  #16 {main}]]&gt;</m:Trace></m:GenericFault></env:Detail>
        </env:Fault>
     </env:Body>
  </env:Envelope>
```

---

I've tracked down the error conditions. It is caused by the magento U training module \Training\Category. When the ExtensionInterface class Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryExtensionInterface is generated the getCountries() method's annotation looks like this:

```
/**
 * @return array|null
 */
public function getCountries();
```

It should look like this:

```
/**
 * @return string[]|null
 */
public function getCountries();
```

Does anyone know how to get DI to generate this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, and it was actually really obvious (facepalm). The type is in the extension_attributes.xml.

Training/Cataegory/etc/extension_attributes.xml was this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface">
        <attribute code="countries" type="array" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

It should have been this:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface">
        <attribute code="countries" type="string[]" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```